# Exchanging oauth2 authorization code with access token

Tags: microsoft-metro, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

In my metro application, I am using google drive apps to get the files from drive.
After I get the code, I am getting error 400 (Invalid request) while exchanging it with access token.
This is my POST request:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id=59349429483.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={DELETED_INTENTIONALLY}&code=4%2FY-rI6ye27Msho3mxmkT7cyDxWzDs&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob

The response I am getting is:
Status: 400
Response: {
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}

Could anyone please let me know the problem with my request? I am setting the request parameters exactly as per google's documentation.

Comment: As this looks, you are sending all the parameters in the query string instead of the request body. Please include the code where you do this into your question.

Comment: odd looking redirect_uri